# Django Middleware extend self.request error when not logged in

Tags: django, django-middleware

We know in self.reqeust, there are too many instances like `self.request.user`, `self.request.data` `self.request.authenticator`

I am trying to extend or make `self.request.person` with `self.request.person` instance, I should get my `Person` Model instance

this is my model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='auth_user',
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

this is my `middleware.py` file

```
from account.models import Person

class PersonMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        person = Person.objects.filter(auth_user=request.user.id).first()
        request.person = person
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

**Currently is working fine for logged-in user**

but the problem, when I go to incognito mode and visit the admin page, it threw me an error that **anonymous user doesn't have attribute request.user.id**

to solve this, I write a condition like this `if request.user.is_authenticated:` but it wasn't solved the issue, I guess, I wrote my middleware wrongly, can anyone help me to achieve this?

What is the right way to write middleware to extend self.request to get  self.request.person?

Comment: What does it have to do with django-rest-framework ??? (tag removed).

Comment: "to solve this, I write a condition like this if request.user.is_authenticated: but it wasn't solved the issue," => then why don't you post THIS version of the code and the matching error message and traceback ?

Comment: Oh and yes: you may want to read the doc for `OneToOneField` - like for all relationships, it creates a reverse accessor so you can just use `request.user.person` (for authenticated users of course - won't work for anonymous users obviously, but you have to treat those differently anyway).

Comment: Sorry if i am rude. I checked documentation, there is not and checked in my project, there is nothing like request.user.person

Comment: You explicitely renamed the 'person' reverse accessor to "auth_user" (the `related_name` argument). Remove this from your field definition and `user.person` will work as expected __for authenticated user that have a related `Person` record__.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add the middleware and add `person` attribute with request. You can easily access it anywhere like this:

```
request.user.person
```

Or you can do like this(checking if the user is authenticated):

```
if request.user.is_autheticated:
     print(request.user.person)
```

Also in template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.person }}
{% endif %}
```

This is possible because of [**`OneToOne`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation between User model and Person Model. So I think you should remove the middleware.

Comment: nope, I am pretty sure I am right. Have you tried `self.request.user.person` if the user is authenticated?

Comment: Also, please check the documentation regarding OneToOne relation attached with this answer. Finally avoid writting middleware for this where you can get the data from request.user.person, because this middleware will hit the DB each time you make a request to server, which is not a big deal but still an overhead

Comment: Yes, I tried like this, see  print(self.request.user.person, '-----------------------------------')

Comment: @mamuncode while it isn't the answer you asked for, I kindly suggest you re-read it with attention and think twice about how you would handle the case of anonymous users with your middleware (once the current issue is "solved" I mean).

Comment: "How do you think there is perosn attribute exist without middleware?" => https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/